# How do I make a generic still observable when using implicit operator (or is there a better way)?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, inotifypropertychanged

I created a generic observable wrapper class so I can just wrap any object to make it observable (much nicer than abusing observablecollection I think). This works perfectly, but I have to use Thing.Value = newValue rather than just Thing = newValue. I added implicit operators, which seems to make the latter partially work, when using Thing = newValue it gets the right value, but the GUI element binding to it is not updating. I think it is either not notifying or losing track of the subscriber, possibly because it is a new object, but not sure. Perhaps the implicit operator needs to return the same object after setting the value, but I have not figured out how to reference it yet.

How do I get Thing = newValue to still be observable?
Edit: copying the example from code block up here for clarity.
How do I get StatusVisibility = Visibility.Visible to be observable? My goal is to not have to add .Value every time I assign a value to an observable.

```cs
    public class Observable<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Observable(T value = default(T))
        {
            Value = value;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private T value;
        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return value;
            }
            set
            {
                this.value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public static implicit operator Observable<T>(T value)
        {
            return new Observable<T>(value);
        }
        public static implicit operator T(Observable<T> value)
        {
            return (T)value;
        }
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //WPF GUI element binds to this
        public static Observable<Visibility> StatusVisibility { get; set; }
            = new Observable<Visibility> { Value = Visibility.Hidden };
        //GUI updates when this is called
        StatusVisibility.Value = Visibility.Visible;
        //GUI element does not update when this is called
        StatusVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: Since you give no hint about the type of `newValue` or the type of `Thing`, nobody here can tell you whether or not either type implements INotifyPropertyChanged properly. Can you clarify your question? Incidentally, *"much nicer than abusing observablecollection I think"* suggests that you may have some mistaken notions about what observablecollection does. Lastly, your window class won't compile.

Comment: The issue with the implicit operator is that you don't update the value on the existing object, but instead create a new one that isn't going to have the `PropertyChanged` event setup.  You should just stick with setting the `Value` property after creating the object.

Comment: If you want to raise a propertychanged notification when you assign a new value to `StatusVisibility`, you need to do so in the setter of `StatusVisibility`. What part of *replacing* the value of `StatusVisibility` do you think will call the setter of the *old value* of `StatusVisibility`? `StatusVisibility` needs to be readonly, so it can't be replaced, and all you can do is update their Value property. IMO it's not worth having to put `.Value` everywhere in your code forever just to avoid a little typing up front, but you'll have your own preferences.

Comment: It's not always productive to try to reinvent something before you fully understand it, and when you do fully understand it, you often come to see that it didn't get the way it is by accident.

Comment: I copied the real world example up to the top for clarity, but see the bottom of the code block for full context. This is copied from a working app and works exactly as I want, minus the problem of not wanting to type .Value so often. Previously I was using "public ObservableCollection<string> Input { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Input" };" for example, and in both cases the GUI elements update.

Comment: You have to type .Value everywhere. There's no way for your `operator Observable<T>()` to get its hands on the lvalue from the assignment expression it's in. Are you saying you previously made all of your properties ObservableCollections with one element, and then you replaced the element to change the value? Have you considered writing an observable `Dictionary<String, dynamic>` class, using that for all your viewmodels, and declaring every reference in your entire application `dynamic`? I think that's your best bet.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was because it was creating a new object, I am just hoping we can figure out how to reference the original. It is worth it if we can, it is a problem that only needs solved once. And yes I am saying I have been using ObservableCollections to bind to when I want it observable, sometimes with 1 element, sometimes a few. I am not saying it is good, but it worked while I figured out a catch all option I like more.

Comment: You cannot reference the original, it's not supported by the language. Your only option is to use `.Value` (or something similar), otherwise you will always be creating a new object, and replacing the previous one.

Comment: [You might look at fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) if you object to implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in the conventional way.

Comment: Or just a custom snippet that adds raisepropertychanged() to the setter of propfull. Snippets are easy. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28219.aspx  Using an observablecollection for all properties in viewmodels is not a good plan.

Comment: Custom snippets are wonderfully useful in a boilerplate-heavy environment like WPF, but it’s not an exotic solution.